# In SPSS, Python doesn't find pandas even though it's installed

Tags: python, pandas, pip, anaconda, spss

I have the SPSS Python 3 home directory location pointed to an Anaconda virtual environment directory where I have Python 3.8 installed. (Note I'm in Windows 10.)

[image]

When I directed SPSS to my base Python 3.9 installation, it threw an error saying it couldn't find Python 3.8 in the directory. Switching to 3.8 in a virtual environment fixed that problem, and I can run Python fine here:

[image]

I also have pandas installed there:

[image]

However, when I try to import pandas in SPSS, either SPSS or Python can't find pandas:

[image]

I'm guessing that Python can't find it, since this is the typical Python error for when a module isn't installed. This makes me think SPSS somehow isn't really getting pointed where I think it is, but I check the Python version with `sys.version`, and it's the 3.8 Python version that's only in the `spss-venv` environment where pandas is installed.

In addition, I can install and use pandas with no problem if I go straight to `spss-venv` in PowerShell:

[image]

If SPSS is really pointed to the right place and pandas is installed, why isn't Python recognizing that pandas is installed, and why does it only happen in SPSS?

Comment: Did you try restarting SPSS?

Comment: I'm almost sure I've restarted it more than once, but I just tried again and it seems to have resolved the issue, which makes me think it's actually been open for several days, though that would be very strange. So I'm unsure if it's possible it just hadn't gotten a chance to re-load or if it's something that may pop up again.

Comment: At any rate, I can't delete the question while there's a bounty on it

Answer (score 0):

restart spss and it should work
or add this line to your python syntax:

```
sys.path.insert(0, path/to/python/modules)
```